# Comparing two 2D Matrix's for Unique Points

Tags: c++, math, matrix

I'm currently working on a game whereby I will have a player traversing a 2D matrix. I want to be able to modify the environment around the player based on his location, as part of a rendering process.

Basically, the player will be at point x,y and will have 2 points around him at all times. The player might move x,y points in any direction and I need to know what the old no longer necessary pointers are, and also the new points the player is close to.

I've drawn up a quick diagram of what I mean:

[image: Diagram of Matrix's]

I need a list of the old points (in red), and the new points (in green) that I can iterate over to perform actions on.

I'll be writing this method in C++, so I'm really looking for the sudo-logic steps required to make this happen. I'm about 50% way through my own way of doing it, but I believe it to be wholly inefficient and I also believe that is a simple mathematical way to do this.

Comment: What approach are you using now?

Comment: There is an approach which is very fast that uses simple arithmetic, I'll see if I can roll up a quick sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the most efficient way would be computing a rectangle-rectangle subtraction that may seem difficult and with a lot of cases, but indeed it's not that hard:

```
struct Rect{
    int x0, y0, x1, y1;
    Rect(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1)
        : x0(x0), y0(y0), x1(x1), y1(y1)
    {}
};

std::vector<Rect> subtract(const Rect& a, const Rect& b) {
    std::vector<Rect> result;
    if (a.y1 <= b.y0 || a.y0 >= b.y1 || a.x1 <= b.x0 || a.x0 >= b.x1) {
        // Trivial case: rectangles are not overlapping
        result.push_back(a);
    } else {
        int ystart = a.y0, yend = a.y1;
        if (ystart < b.y0) { // Something visible above
            result.push_back(Rect(a.x0, ystart, a.x1, b.y0));
            ystart = b.y0;
        }
        if (yend > b.y1) { // Something visible below
            result.push_back(Rect(a.x0, b.y1, a.x1, yend));
            yend = b.y1;
        }
        if (a.x0 < b.x0) { // Something visible on the left
            result.push_back(Rect(a.x0, ystart, b.x0, yend));
        }
        if (a.x1 > b.x1) { // Something visible on the right
            result.push_back(Rect(b.x1, ystart, a.x1, yend));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The above function given two rectangles `A` and `B` returns a vector of rectangles with the result of `A-B`. This vector may be empty (`B` covers `A`) or may have from one to four rectangles (four is when `B` is stricly contained in `A`, thus the result will be a rectangle with a rectangular hole in it).

Using this function you can easily compute `new-old` and `old-new` areas.

Note that the coordinate schema used in the above code assumes the point-base coordinate system (not a pixel-based coordinate system):

[image]

In the above picture note that horizontal X coordinates of rectangles go from 0 to W (not W-1) and vertical Y coordinates go from 0 to H (and not to H-1).

Pixels are just rectangles of area 1 with coordinates `(x, y)-(x+1, y+1)`; the center of this pixel is `(x+0.5, y+0.5)`. A rectangle with `x0==x1` or `y0==y1` is empty.

Note also that the code assumes (and returns) non-empty oriented rectangles, i.e. `x0<x1 && y0<y1`.

This approach of separating the concept of pixel coordinate from the concept of point coordinate simplifies a lot of the pixel math: for example rectangle area is `width*height` and not `(width-1)*(height-1)`.

A little program to test with your input case is the following

```
void print_result(const char *name,
                  const std::vector<Rect>& rects)
{
    printf("Result '%s' (%i rects):\n", name, int(rects.size()));
    for (int i=0,n=rects.size(); i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("  %i) (%i, %i) - (%i, %i)\n",
               i+1,
               rects[i].x0, rects[i].y0,
               rects[i].x1, rects[i].y1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    Rect A(1, 1, 6, 6);
    Rect B(3, 2, 8, 7);
    print_result("A-B", subtract(A, B));
    print_result("B-A", subtract(B, A));
    return 0;
}
```

and the output of this program is

```
Result 'A-B' (2 rects):
  1) (1, 1) - (6, 2)
  2) (1, 2) - (3, 6)
Result 'B-A' (2 rects):
  1) (3, 6) - (8, 7)
  2) (6, 2) - (8, 6)
```

Comment: FYI this isn't entirely correct - Your trivial case subtraction will find that there are new and old points if the 2 boxes are right on top of each other due to the <= instead of <.

Comment: @S.Richmond: No. The code is correct; simply it's based on the point coordinate system and not on the pixel coordinate system. I've added an explanation. The point coordinate system is much nicer when dealing with pixel-accurate rendering and allows to avoid both special cases and the need of `-1` and `+1` in the code.

Comment: Ah! Well that makes a lot more sense! I've been having a lot of trouble with my code due to the fact that I was working with the pixel coord system. The problem I'm facing is how I loop over the returned coords properly. For example, I get (4,4)(5,8) returned. Which is 1 row of 5 'points'. But I can't figure out a way to loop over that without getting 2 rows instead. For loop:
`for(int x = block->x0; x <= block->x1; x++) {
 for(int y = block->y0; y <= block->y1; y++) {
 }
}`

Comment: Using the point coordinate system you must loop from x0 to x1 **excluded**... for example `for (int y=r.y0; y<r.y1; y++) { for (int x=r.x0; x<r.x1; x++) { ... } }`.

Comment: Thats what I've already got. And won't the inner for loop always fail because x < x1 (4 < 4) will always return FALSE? Additionally, I still don't understand why subtract returns the full region when the 2 regions given are exactly the same. Will I have to add code to detect that?

Comment: @S.Richmond: There was a typo in the first check. Two intervals are not overlapping if `a.x0>=b.x1` (a starts after b ends) or if `a.x1<=b.x0` (a ends before b starts). If this happens for either x or y there is no intersection and `a-b` is `a`.

Answer (score 1):

I've re written my original answer so it covers all cases and hopefully makes a bit more sense: (It's php not C++, but it was easier to write it out like this than to write out sudo-logic. Hopefully it will explain itself a bit better now.)

A rectangle (or square in this case) can be represented by it's bottom left and top right coordinate. For this example, $Rectangle[0] is the bottom left coordinate, with $Rectangle[0]['x'] being the x value of the bottom left coordinate and $Rectangle[0]['y'] being the y value of the bottom left coordinate. $Rectangle[1] is the top right coordinate.

This could be modified for something that will only deal with squares to hold only one vertex coordinate and the edge length.

There are 4 possibilities for movement:
1: No movement happened, the squares are in the same place. In this case all four corner points of the green rectangle will be inside the blue rectangle.
2: Enough movement happened to cause there to be no overlap between the two squares. In this case none of the four corner points of the green rectangle will be inside the blue rectangle.
3: Movement has happened in only one direction (x or y) and not far enough to remove all over lap. In this case 2 of the four corner points of the green rectangle will be inside the blue rectangle.
4: Movement has happened in both x and y directions and not far enough to remove overlap entirely. In this case one of the four corner points of the green rectangle will be inside the blue rectangle.

Each case can be handled slightly differently:
1 - You don't need to iterate over any squares.
2 - You need to iterate over all of the squares in the blue rectangle and all of the squares in the green rectangle.
3 - You need to iterate over the squares defined by:

```
function getOnlyOverlapRectangle($FirstRectangle, $SecondRectangle)
    {
        $PointOne['x'] = $FirstRectangle[0]['x'];
        $PointOne['y'] = $FirstRectangle[0]['y'];
        $PointTwo['x'] = $FirstRectangle[0]['x'];
        $PointTwo['y'] = $FirstRectangle[1]['y'];
        $PointThree['x'] = $FirstRectangle[1]['x'];
        $PointThree['y'] = $FirstRectangle[1]['y'];
        $PointFour['x'] = $FirstRectangle[1]['x'];
        $PointFour['y'] = $FirstRectangle[]['y'];

        //left edge
        if(checkVertexInside($PointOne,$SecondRectangle) && checkVertexInside($PointTwo,$SecondRectangle))
        {
            $overlapRectangle[0]['x'] = $SecondRectangle[1]['x'];
        }
        else
        {
            $overlapRectangle[0]['x'] = $FirstRectangle[0]['x'];
        }

        //bottom edge
        if(checkVertexInside($PointOne,$SecondRectangle) && checkVertexInside($PointFour,$SecondRectangle))
        {
            $overlapRectangle[0]['y'] = $SecondRectangle[1]['y'];
        }
        else
        {
            $overlapRectangle[0]['y'] = $FirstRectangle[0]['y'];
        }

        //right edge
        if(checkVertexInside($PointThree,$SecondRectangle) && checkVertexInside($PointFour,$SecondRectangle))
        {
            $overlapRectangle[1]['x'] = $SecondRectangle[0]['x'];
        }
        else
        {
            $overlapRectangle[1]['x'] = $FirstRectangle[1]['x'];
        }

        //top edge
        if(checkVertexInside($PointTwo,$SecondRectangle) && checkVertexInside($PointThree,$SecondRectangle))
        {
            $overlapRectangle[1]['y'] = $SecondRectangle[0]['y'];
        }
        else
        {
            $overlapRectangle[1]['y'] = $FirstRectangle[1]['y'];
        }


        return $overlapRectangle;
    }
```

4 - You need to iterate over the squares defined by:

```
//Gets subset of $FirstRectangle that is outside of $SecondRectangle
function getFirstOverlapRectangle($FirstRectangle, $SecondRectangle)
    {
        //left edge
        $Point['x'] = $FirstRectangle[0]['x'];
        $Point['y'] = $FirstRectangle[1]['y'];
        if(checkVertexInside($Point,$SecondRectangle))
        {
            $overlapRectangle[0]['x'] = $SecondRectangle[1]['x'];
        }
        else
        {
            $overlapRectangle[0]['x'] = $FirstRectangle[0]['x'];
        }

        //bottom edge
        if($FirstRectangle[0]['y'] < $SecondRectangle[0]['y'] < $FirstRectangle[1]['y'])
        {
            $overlapRectangle[0]['y'] = $SecondRectangle[0]['y'];
        }
        else
        {
            $overlapRectangle[0]['y'] = $SecondRectangle[1]['y'];
        }

        //right edge
        $overlapRectangle[1]['x'] = min($FirstRectangle[1]['x'],$SecondRectangle[0]['x']);

        //top edge
        $overlapRectangle[1]['y'] = $FirstRectangle[1]['y'];

        return $overlapRectangle;
    }

    //Gets second subset of $FirstRectangle that is outside of $SecondRectangle
    function getSecondOverlapRectangle($FirstRectangle, $SecondRectangle)
    {
        //top edge
        if($FirstRectangle[0]['y'] < $SecondRectangle[0]['y'] < $FirstRectangle[1]['y'])
        {
            $overlapRectangle[1]['y'] = $SecondRectangle[0]['y'];
        }
        else
        {
            $overlapRectangle[1]['y'] = $SecondRectangle[1]['y'];
        }

        //bottom edge
        $overlapRectangle[0]['y'] = $FirstRectangle[0]['y'];

        //left edge
        $Point['x'] = $SecondRectangle[1]['x'];
        $Point['y'] = $SecondRectangle[1]['y'];
        if(checkVertexInside($Point,$FirstRectangle))
        {
            $overlapRectangle[0]['x'] = $SecondRectangle[1]['x'];
        }
        else
        {
            $overlapRectangle[0]['x'] = $FirstRectangle[0]['x'];
        }

        //right edge
        $Point['x'] = $FirstRectangle[0]['x'];
        $Point['y'] = $FirstRectangle[1]['y'];
        if(checkVertexInside($Point,$SecondRectangle))
        {
            $overlapRectangle[1]['x'] = $FirstRectangle[0]['x'];
        }
        else
        {
            $overlapRectangle[1]['x'] = $SecondRectangle[1]['x'];
        }


        return $overlapRectangle;
    }
```

So a possible solution would work like this:

Work out how many corners of the green rectangle are inside the blue rectangle.
Switch on that number:
 0: iterate over all green rectangle points and all blue rectangle points
 1: iterate over result of getFirstOverlapRectangle and getSecondOverlapRectangle
 2: iterate over result of getOnlyOverlapRectangle
 3: this shouldn't happen...
 4: don't iterate over any squares.

Iterating would have to work something like this:

```
for($CurrentXCoord = $OldSquaresOne[0]['x'] + 0.5; $CurrentXCoord < $OldSquaresOne[1]['x'];  $CurrentXCoord ++)
    {
        for($CurrentYCoord = $OldSquaresOne[0]['y'] + 0.5; $CurrentYCoord < $OldSquaresOne[1]['y'];  $CurrentYCoord ++)
        {
            //do stuff.
        }
    }
```

The +0.5 ensures that you don't go over boundary points twice so you reference the squares inside the blue/green squares by their center coordinate instead of corner coordinate.

The checkVertexInside function would be something along the lines of:

```
function checkVertexInside($Point, $Rectangle)
    {
        if
        (
            $Point['x'] <= $Rectangle[1]['x'] && $Point['x'] >= $Rectangle[0]['x']
            && $Point['y'] <= $Rectangle[1]['y'] && $Point['y'] >= $Rectangle[0]['y']
        )
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    function getRectanglePoint($topFlag,$rightFlag,$Rectangle)
    {
        $Point['x'] = $Rectangle[$rightFlag]['x'];
        $Point['y'] = $Rectangle[$topFlag]['y'];
        return $Point;
    }
```

Comment: Actually this doesn't take into account all of the possiblilites. Is an approach though, and you could think about it some more to make it cover all of them. Rectangle subtraction looks better though.

Comment: Yeah looks pretty good, but I'm a little confused by it to be honest. Thanks for helping out though. :)

Comment: Basically it splits the non overlapping area up into rectangles and iterates over the points in those. Except that it doesn't for all cases.

Answer (score 1):

This is a general approach for outputting red and green non-overlapping points.  Call the function find_points to do the work.  This assumes you have a Points class to hold a set of points with an add(x,y) method for adding one point to it.

```
struct Box {
  int x1; // min x value
  int x2; // max x value + 1
  int y1; // min y value
  int y2; // max y value + 1
};

Box intersection(const Box &box1,const Box &box2)
{
  int wx1 = max(box1.x1,box2.x1);
  int wx2 = min(box1.x2,box2.x2);
  int wy1 = max(box1.y1,box2.y1);
  int wy2 = min(box1.y2,box2.y2);
  Box result = {wx1,wx2,wy1,wy2};
  return result;
}

void output_box(Points &p,int x1,int x2,int y1,int y2)
{
  for (int y=y1; y!=y2; ++y) {
    for (int x=x1; x!=x2; ++x) {
      p.add(x,y);
    }
  }
}

void output_difference(Points &points,const Box &box1,const Box &box2)
{
  output_box(points,box1.x1,box1.x2,box1.y1,box2.y1);
  output_box(points,box1.x1,box2.x1,box2.y1,box2.y2);
  output_box(points,box2.x2,box1.x2,box2.y1,box2.y2);
  output_box(points,box1.x1,box1.x2,box2.y2,box1.y2);
}

void find_points(Points &red,Points &green,const Box &red_box,const Box &green_box)
{
  Box white_box = intersection(red_box,green_box);
  output_difference(red,red_box,white_box);
  output_difference(green,green_box,white_box);
}
```

EDIT: There was a bug in calculating wy2 -- now fixed.

Comment: Just to clarify, to use above mentioned code one would:
find_points(pRed, pGreen, red_box, green_box);

Done?

Comment: Just dropped the code in and playing with it now, however I noticed "Points" isn't an actual type. Were you expecting me to fix that up with whatever I use?

Comment: Yes, Points would be whatever data structure that you want to hold the points.

Comment: Hrm this doesn't appear to be working as intended. Performing the above code with box1 and box2 as both ((4,4) (8,8)) results as all points being recognised at both new and old.
I'm debugging this now to try to work it out.

Comment: Ooops!  There was a bug in calculating wy2.  It is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a list of the old points (red).

   Make a list of the new points (green).

   Iterate over one list. For each point, look for it in the other list, and if it's there, delete it from both lists.

**EDIT:**

Let me rephrase that:

1. Make a list of the points in the old neighborhood (inside the blue border).

   Make a list of the points in the new neighborhood (inside the green border).

   Iterate over one list. For each point, look for it in the other list, and if it's there, delete it from both lists.

You will be left with a list of the points no longer visible (red) and the newly-visible points (green).

Comment: The question is to find the red and green sections based on the two areas (blue and green squares). In other words I can't yet take steps 1 or 2.